# iOS Universal Deeplinking not Working

Tags: ios, deep-linking, universal, apple-app-site-associate

When I long press on the hyperlink https://www.myapp.com in the Notes app, I don't see any "Open in My App" option. I have made sure of the following:

- I have a apple-app-site-association file hosted at
  https://www.myapp.com/apple-app-site-association
- I have added applinks:www.myapp.com in associated domains in the
  entitlement file.
- Entitlement file is added in the target bundle resources

How else do I debug this? Universal deeplinking is just not working!

Comment: [https://sailthru.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/217102466-Universal-Links-Troubleshooting-and-FAQ](https://sailthru.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/217102466-Universal-Links-Troubleshooting-and-FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

I was supposed to test the testFlight build and not the one installed from XCode.

Comment: Yes, it started working in the build downloaded from testflight. After that even when you install the dev build from the xCode, deeplinking works.